# Get percentage in loop

Tags: php, oracle

```
<?php
    $LSum = 0;
    while ( $dataApiUsage = $ResApiUsage->fetchAssoc() ) {
        foreach ( $ResL as $RowL) {
            if ($dataApiUsage['termid'] === $RowL->termid) {
                $LCount++;
                print $dataApiUsage['termname'];
                print round($RowL->page_views/$LSum, 2);
                print $RowL->page_views;
                $LSum+= $RowL->page_views;
```

This is my loop to fetch data from database (ORACLE). I just added this code to get the percentage of each entry. But its fails in first loop itself because of division by zero.

Comment: Then check for zeros before dividing. What doyou want to do if LSum is zero?

Comment: Well quite simply you are setting `$LSum = 0;` at the top of your loop so the first time through your loop the calculation will always generate this error. Review your logic

Comment: I understood. But is there any other way to get it.

Comment: drup: what do you want to achieve? if simply a percentage then (num1/num2)*100 where num2>num1. Apply to your demand/code-flow

Comment: I am displaying each page view in the loop and adding each page view to get the total page view. I need to get the percentage value of page view with in the loop. Like Page `A` viewed by 5 times and total page view is 50. So percentage for page `A` is (5/50)*100.